# Error Reading User Input into Array

Tags: c#, input

So I'm intentionally overcomplicating a homework assignment I was given because I was bored and wanted to learn more about c#. The original assignment is as follows:

"Compute the average of five exam scores ranging between 50 and 90.  Declare and perform a compile-time initialization with the five values.  Use a constant to define the number of scores.  Display all scores and the average value formatted with no digits to the right of the decimal."

So I decided rather than just putting the 5 scores in, I'd allow the user to input them into an array and then calculate it from that.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 test scores between 50 and 90:");
int i = 0;
double total = 0;
double[] Scores;
Scores = new double[5];

while (i < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input Score " + (i + 1) + ":");
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    Scores[i] = double.Parse(input);
    total += Scores[i];
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine("The average of the scores is: " + (total/5));
```

The issue is that the `Scores[i] = double.Parse(input);` is throwing an error saying that the input is in the wrong format. So the program won't even run to let me put IN an input, but it says the input format is incorrect.

Any suggestions? I'm probably missing something obvious.

EDIT: Ok, so what ended up working was changing the code to

```
Console.WriteLine("Input Score " + (i + 1) + ":");
Scores[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
total += Scores[i];
i++;
```

Not sure what it actually changed but it seems to work pretty flawlessly!

Comment: Are you positive that your input is definitely a number that can be represented as a double?

Comment: What are you entering when it gives you an error? If you are using decimals, what is the decimal separator that you are using? Is it a comma (,) or a period (.) ?

Comment: When you say "program won't even run" are you saying that it doesn't compile, that VisualStudio is underlining it in red and giving you an error, or is it giving you an error when you actually attempt to run the compiled program?

Comment: Wait a minute are you writing a console application, because like @Leon mentioned if you are getting an error trying to run it without pausing to let you type input, your prject might not be a console project.

Comment: I don't know either, your original code worked fine as is for me when I pasted it into a VS2008 application.

Comment: There is technically nothing wrong with this code, other than the fact that it has no error handling for improper input. You've also stated that it doesn't run and ever allow input, which is very vague. Typically the exception you're receiving would be caused by invalid input but you've stated it never allows input, which is strange. So maybe some helpful things here would be when you're getting this exception, what version of .Net you're targeting, what IDE you're using, and as @TYY has stated you may not have your project set to the correct output type.

Comment: Also, your edit literally doesn't make sense as to why this would have resolved your issue. Effectively, it shouldn't have changed anything whatsoever. So it would be great if you could still provide the requested information so we can pinpoint the issue and hopefully save someone else a headache down the road.